# itoa () does not work on 32bit tdm-gcc 5.1 even on including stdlib.h

Tags: c++, char, 32bit-64bit, itoa

I have a made a c++ program which uses itoa (). I compiled it on 64Bit compiler(TDM-GCC-5.1), it compiled and worked. But when i compiled it using 32 bit TDM-GCC-5.1 compiler i get the error itoa () was not declared in this scope. I tried compiling this on two different 32 bit machines still i got the same error and it by including cstdlib and stdlib.h still the same error in both the cases.
It compiles and runs fine on a 64 bit machine. But why doesn't it do so on a 32 bit compiler??

Can you please suggest some alternative for 32 bit ?

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

main()
{
int test;
char t[2];

itoa(test,t,10);
}
```

Compiler output:

```
C:\Users\hello\Desktop\Untitled1df.cpp  In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\hello\Desktop\Untitled1df.cpp  [Error] 'itoa' was not declared in this scope
```

Screenshot: [the IDE screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w3xV.png)

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifyable example in terms of code - i.e. something that we can take and compile and that then gives the error.

Comment: I would suggest not using itoa which makes conversion detection difficult.

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: i want to convert store a integer value in a character array.

Comment: @acraig5075 i tried with algorithm, still the same error

Comment: `itoa` is not a standard function, and `main()` is not valid C++. Stick to the standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itoa` is not a standard function. It is provided by some implementations and not by others. Avoid it in portable software.

The 64-bit version of TDM GCC in its default mode happens to provide itoa, while the 32-bit version doesn't. In order to keep the behaviour consistent between versions, try e.g. `-std=c++11 -DNO_OLDNAMES -D_NO_OLDNAMES`.

A standards-conforming alternative would be for example

```
char buffer[20];
snprintf (buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", number);
```

Speaking of portability, `main()` without `int` is a grave error which is erroneously left without a diagnostic in some versions of GCC for Windows. It's a bug in these version of GCC. In addition, accessing an uninitialised variable `test` triggers undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thankyou and refering to the main () thing....i am a 12 grade student. So concepts of efficiency don't matter as i only make proof of concept softwares for project which dont have to be released in the market, so i have to ignore efficiency and the programs are  not mission critical. I never knew not using int is a grave error as my compiler never pointed that out. Anyways thankyou for informing me.
And this just a example code so i didnt mind following programming guidelines. The actual code is pretty big with 6-7 header files, so i didnt find it appropriate to post the code.

Comment: You must be meaning _correctness_ when you say "efficiency". I'd also assume that if you enable a minimal level of warnings on your compiler, it will point out malformed code on that level, unless it is some particular old version that hasn't been fixed.